# Undefined reference to class?

Tags: c++, class

NetBeans interpret weird my code. In main function I have code:

```
SequenceAlignment align;
align.Alignment( local, seqs, argv[4], matrix)
```

But NetBeans show:

```
cpp:91: undefined reference to `SequenceAlignment::Alignment(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, char*, ScoreMatrix&)'
```

To be honest I do not know what to think. It works before, but now suddenly it doesn't.

Comment: I think you're missing a semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a linker error indicating that the linker can't find an implementation for `SequenceAlignment::Alignment`.  Check to see that you indeed have an implementation of this function and that the code containing that implementation is indeed being compiled and linked.

Comment: "…indeed being compiled" and linked with the final program.

Comment: @Maxpm I just have not copied all, I have semicolon in this place in code ;-) 

@templatetypedef Yes, I have implementation. After writing Makefile myself everything compile as it should. ;-)